# In practice, is it good to add macros in API headers which way change the layout (or size) of a class?

Tags: c++

For example if I have a header like this:

```
class Example {
  int a;
#if TEST
  int b;
#endif
};
```

how can I distribute my binary library, to avoid user getting an ABI problem?

P.S. I asked this because I used a library and it is compiled with the definition `TEST`, while I'm not define it when I include the header, which leads to the size in header does not match with the library. I'm interesting how to avoid this if I'm going to distribute some libraries someday.

Comment: It's normal for ABIs to have such macros, but usually they would have a much better name.  Hopefully, somewhere it is documented exactly _what_ `TEST` is used for.  Then you would understand when/why to compile the library with that macro defined and you would match the definition in your own program by defining it before including the header.

Comment: Is the class Example in your library or is it some third party lib you intent to use ? To improve the question try to give more background or how the actual case.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to provide a init function for your library and define in the header, and a function like `ensure_TEST_is_set` that is defined in library/binary.

```
void ensure_TEST_is_set();

void init_library() {
   #if TEST
   ensure_TEST_is_set();
   #endif
}
```

```
void ensure_TEST_is_set() {
   #ifndef TEST
   throw std::runtime_error("Library not ABI compatible, TEST is not matching");
   #endif
}
```

So the `ensure_TEST_is_set` is shipped part of the binary, and depending on if `TEST` was set when compiling or not, it will throw an exception when called.

The `#if TEST` in the `init_library` - as it is defined in the header - will be evaluated by everytime the header is used.